# FTDI : impossible to open port C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7, usb, serial-port

I am currently using FTDI FT232R to convert USB line to serial line (in particular to RS485).
My program is working under WIndows 7 (64bit) and it is compiled in Visual C++ 2010.
I'm using FTDI library whose guide can be found in this link

[http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer%27s_Guide%28FT_000071%29.pdf)

If I launch it "normally"(simple double click on the icon), the program works on some PC (not all), while if I use "run as administrator" it doesn't work on any PCs which I could tested (always Windows 7).
All the drivers have been updated to the last version (2.8.24.0)
In particular the error which I have is : 
FT_INVALID_HANDLE
Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks
Giorgio

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you attempt to open the port? Also, are you able to open the port with CreateFile()?